# How do I find the source of soft page faults?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have Windows 7 x64 computer that according to Performance Monitor has 70,000 page faults / second when idling. That's seems like a lot to me (every other computer I check has basically 0 page faults / second when idling).

If I use Resource Monitor or Process Explorer to check hard faults, I see that they are basically 0. So all the page faults are soft.

Normally, soft page faults are not a problem, but I suspect they might be causing issues for this computer given there are so many. I would like to identify what programs are causing the soft faults.

Are there any tools that exist that display the number of soft page faults for each process?

Comment: Finally found the source of all these page faults: the Windows Search service. Disabled that, the page fault total went down to 3,000 / second, and everything runs great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) has per-process columns for "Hard Faults Delta" and "Page Faults Delta". The difference between the two is how many soft page faults are occurring, and you know exactly which processes are generating them:

[image]

The above screenshot shows an empty column, but that's only because the computer was essentially idle. It *does* show the hard faults when they occur, e.g. when launching a heavyweight program.

Answer (score 2):

According to this, pfmon.exe will do it.
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1687

I was able to download it from
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229
and I was able to use it successfully.

Good luck.

Comment: While the links may help, can you describe *how* it helps? What is the process or set of steps you would go through to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly these soft faults are coming from memory shared by two or more applications - what have you got running on there? if it's something like MS Office that uses a lot of shared memory then you can completely forget about these 'errors' (they're not really errors to be honest, just MMU table coherency notifications).

Answer (score 0):

Please, give a try to Process Explorer (tool of Sysinternals suite)

You'll find it here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Once running, just got to check **Page Fault Delta**
what you will find under `View | Select Columns...` hitting on `Process Memory tab`